# python mysterious command //#::

Tags: python, tags, ipython

Looking for a tag that I could parse
either in Python and in some other languages
without bugging anything,
I found this strange thing

```py
    In [15]: print('standard python')    
    In [16]: //#::         
        ...:  
        ...: hello
        ...: print('hey')
        ...: exit()  
        ...:  
        ...: seems to wait for something  
        ...: & I have no idea what ???  
        ...:
```

Anybody got any clue?

Comment: have you tried `#//` ?

Comment: Can't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Weird this behaviour in Python.

The operator `#::` is a Scala thing that is defined as an [extractor for pattern matching streams](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream%24@#%3A%3A).

The operator `//` is a floor division in Python, which is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/introduction.html). But for Scala would be a comment.

If you are looking for an unusual delimiter, try something like `_||_`

```
field 1_||_field 2_||_field 3
```

Hope this information helps.